# how prepare API response to use with jsonDecoder in swift

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder

when i call API and get response from server with Alamofire, i want use "data" object from json

this data come from API

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "hasError": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "userSession": "43a1bd70-26bf-11e9-9ccd-00163eaf6bb4"
        }
    ],
    "message": "ok"
}
```

and i want map `data` to my `AuthModel`

this is my `AuthModel`:

```
struct AuthModel: Codable {
    let userSession: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userSession = "userSession"
    }
}
```

i coded this lines but it isn't work:

```
if let responseObject = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
    if let hasError = responseObject["hasError"] as? Bool {
        guard !hasError else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let authModel = try decoder.decode(AuthModel.self, from: responseObject["data"])
        } catch {
            print("Parse Error: ",error)
        }
    }
}
```

this does not work because `responseObject["data"]` is not NSData Type

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your API response is a pattern that indicates:

- Do we have any problem (error)?
- Do we have our expected data?

Based on these, we can use `Enum` and `Generics`. For example:

```swift
class ResponseObject<T: Codable>: Codable {

    private var code        : Int
    private var hasError    : Bool
    private var message     : String
    private var data        : T?

    var result: Result {
        guard !hasError else { return .error(code, message) }
        guard let data = data else { return .error(0, "Data is not ready.") }
        return .value(data)
    }

    enum Result {
        case error(Int, String)
        case value(T)
    }

}
```

and we can use `ResponseObject` with our expected `data`:

```swift
let responseString = """
{
    "code": 200,
    "hasError": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "userSession": "43a1bd70-26bf-11e9-9ccd-00163eaf6bb4"
        }
    ],
    "message": "ok"
}
"""

class AuthObject: Codable {
    var userSession : String

}

if let jsonData = responseString.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        //ResponseObject<[AuthObject]> means: if we don't have error, the `data` object in response, will represent `[AuthObject]`.
        let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject<[AuthObject]>.self, from: jsonData)

        //Using ResponseObject.Result Enum: We have error with related code and message, OR, we have our expected data.
        switch responseObject.result {
        case .error(let code, let message):
            print("Error: \(code) - \(message)")
        case .value(let authObjects):
            print(authObjects.first!.userSession)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `Data` response rather than the deserialized `Dictionary` for example

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseData { response in
```

and decode

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let authModel = try decoder.decode(AuthModel.self, from: response.data!)
```

into these structs

```
struct AuthModel : Decodable {
    let code : Int
    let hasError : Bool
    let message : String
    let data : [Session]
}

struct Session : Decodable {
    let userSession: String
}
```

All CodingKeys are synthesized.

Comment: vow, this api response is pattern of all APIs, so i can't use always code, hasError, message, data in all of my Models

Comment: I just answered the question.